# create a new page in a form dynamically, based on data of the prev. page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a question regarding forms in google-apps-script. Lets say I have already created a form with a single page and a input box for text.
Is it possible to create the follow-up page dynamically, based on the data out of the textbox? Something like:

First Page: insert customer id -> continue -> Second Page: information about the customer.

I know that there are events like onLoad and onSubmit, but there is no onContinue event for example.

Is it possible to create something like that with google-apps-script? What would be the best way to archive such a behavior? 
B.R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `UiApp` service, you have one `doGet()` and one `doPost()` function... but here's a way to extend them to support a dynamic multi-part form. (The example code is borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557536/1677912).

Your `doGet()` simply builds part1 of your form. In the form, however, you need to identify your form *by name*, like this:

```
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId("emailCopyForm");
```

You `doPost()` then, will pass off handling of the post operation to different functions, depending on which form has been submitted. See below. (Also included: `reportFormParameters ()`, a default handler that will display all data collected by a form part.)

```
/**
 * doPost function with multi-form handling. Individual form handlers must
 * return UiApp instances.
 */
function doPost(eventInfo) {
  var app;
  Logger.log("Form ID = %s", eventInfo.parameter.formId);
  // Call appropriate handler for the posted form
  switch (eventInfo.parameter.formId) {
    case 'emailCopyForm':
      app = postEmailCopyForm(eventInfo);
      break;
    default:
      app = reportFormParameters (eventInfo);
      break;
  }
  return app;
}

/**
 * Debug function - returns a UiInstance containing all parameters from the
 * provided form Event.
 *
 * Example of use:
 * <pre>
 *     function doPost(eventInfo) {
 *       return reportFormParameters(eventInfo);
 *     }
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param {Event} eventInfo Event from UiApp Form submission
 *
 * @return {UiInstance}
 */
function reportFormParameters (eventInfo) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(app.createLabel("Form submitted"));
  for (var param in eventInfo.parameter) {
    switch (param) {
      // Skip the noise; these keys are used internally by UiApp
      case 'lib':
      case 'appId':
      case 'formId':
      case 'token':
      case 'csid':
      case 'mid':
        break;

      // Report parameters named in form
      default:
        panel.add(app.createLabel(" - " + param + " = " + eventInfo.parameter[param]));
        break;
    }
  }
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

To generate each form part, subsequent form handlers can use the data retrieved in previous parts to dynamically add new Form objects to the ui.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is some working code](http://pastebin.com/pX5P1NcA) 
that demonstrates a multiple page form.
The code uses a single "hidden" state in a `TextBox` and multiple `SubmitButtons` to allow the user to advance forward and backward through the form sequence, as well as to validate the contents of the form.  The two extra `SubmitButtons` are "rewired" using `ClientHandlers` that simply modify the hidden state prior to form submission.