# Can I develop an wizard application (sequentially submit forms)?

Tags: google-apps-script

In my understanding now, only one doGet() can trigger unique doPost() in a Google Apps Script application.

I would like to perform a ***Software Publisher System*** that user upload the file or fill up revision information in forms and push submit to the next step. The final page will show the input information, send email to guys and complete all operation.

But how do I enter next form after the submit button pushed?

I have tried a method that creating the 2nd step and 3rd step forms in the ***doPost()***, and using **try...catch** to difference which step form triggered the current step, like the following code.
(Because any steps can't get the callback item throw by non-previous step, then it arises an exception)

It works very well but I think it doesn't make sens and very silly. Have any better solutions? Thanks, please.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function doGet(e)
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("AP Publisher");    

  createFileUploadForm(app);

  return app;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function doPost(e) 
{  
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();                 

  try {
    // 2nd step form
    var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;         

    createRevisionForm();
  }
  catch(error) {
    try {
      // 3rd step form
      createConfirmForm(e);
    }
    catch(error2) {
      //Complete       
      sendMail(e);            
      modifySitePageContent(e);            
      saveHistoryFile(e);   

      showConfirmedInfo(e);
    }
  }

  return app;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is copied entirely from [create a new page in a form dynamically, based on data of the prev. page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620836/create-a-new-page-in-a-form-dynamically-based-on-data-of-the-prev-page).*

Using the `UiApp` service, you have one `doGet()` and one `doPost()` function... but here's a way to extend them to support a dynamic multi-part form. (The example code is borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557536/1677912).)

Your `doGet()` simply builds part1 of your form. In the form, however, you need to identify your form *by name*, like this:

```
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId("emailCopyForm");
```

You `doPost()` then, will pass off handling of the post operation to different functions, depending on which form has been submitted. See below. (Also included: `reportFormParameters ()`, a default handler that will display all data collected by a form part.)

```
/**
 * doPost function with multi-form handling. Individual form handlers must
 * return UiApp instances.
 */
function doPost(eventInfo) {
  var app;
  Logger.log("Form ID = %s", eventInfo.parameter.formId);
  // Call appropriate handler for the posted form
  switch (eventInfo.parameter.formId) {
    case 'emailCopyForm':
      app = postEmailCopyForm(eventInfo);
      break;
    default:
      app = reportFormParameters (eventInfo);
      break;
  }
  return app;
}

/**
 * Debug function - returns a UiInstance containing all parameters from the
 * provided form Event.
 *
 * Example of use:
 * <pre>
 *     function doPost(eventInfo) {
 *       return reportFormParameters(eventInfo);
 *     }
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param {Event} eventInfo Event from UiApp Form submission
 *
 * @return {UiInstance}
 */
function reportFormParameters (eventInfo) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(app.createLabel("Form submitted"));
  for (var param in eventInfo.parameter) {
    switch (param) {
      // Skip the noise; these keys are used internally by UiApp
      case 'lib':
      case 'appId':
      case 'formId':
      case 'token':
      case 'csid':
      case 'mid':
        break;

      // Report parameters named in form
      default:
        panel.add(app.createLabel(" - " + param + " = " + eventInfo.parameter[param]));
        break;
    }
  }
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

To generate each form part, subsequent form handlers can use the data retrieved in previous parts to dynamically add new Form objects to the ui.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler to use 3 (or more) different panels in your doGet function with all the items you need and to play with their visibility.

At first only the 1rst panel would be visible and, depending on user input (using client Handlers to handle that) show the next ones (and eventually hide the first one).

In the end the submit button will call the doPost and get all data from the doGet.

Answer (score 0):

First a tip of my hat to Mogsdad. His post(s) were guiding lights in the darkly documented path that led me here. [Here is some working code](http://pastebin.com/pX5P1NcA) 
that demonstrates a multiple page form, i.e. it does the initial `doGet()` and then lets you advance back and forth doing multiple `doPost()`'s.  All this is done in a single `getForm()` function called by both the standard `doGet()` and the `doPost()` functions.

```
// Muliple page form using Google Apps Script

function doGet(eventInfo)  {return GUI(eventInfo)};
function doPost(eventInfo) {return GUI(eventInfo)};

function GUI (eventInfo) {
  var n = (eventInfo.parameter.state == void(0) ? 0 : parseInt(eventInfo.parameter.state));
  var ui = ((n == 0)? UiApp.createApplication() : UiApp.getActiveApplication());
  var Form;
  switch(n){
    case 0: {
      Form = getForm(eventInfo,n); // Use identical forms for demo purpose only
    } break;
    case 1: {
      Form = getForm(eventInfo,n); // In reality, each form would differ but...
    } break;
    default: {
      Form = getForm(eventInfo,n) // each form must abide by (implement) the hidden state variable
    } break;
  }
  return ui.add(Form);
};

function getForm(eventInfo,n) {
  var ui = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  // Increment the ID stored in a hidden text-box
  var state = ui.createTextBox().setId('state').setName('state').setValue(1+n).setVisible(true).setEnabled(false);
  var H1 = ui.createHTML("<H1>Form "+n+"</H1>");
  var H2 = ui.createHTML(
    "<h2>"+(eventInfo.parameter.formId==void(0)?"":"Created by submission of form "+eventInfo.parameter.formId)+"</h2>");

  // Add three submit buttons to go forward, backward and to validate the form
  var Next = ui.createSubmitButton("Next").setEnabled(true).setVisible(true);
  var Back = ui.createSubmitButton("Back").setEnabled(n>1).setVisible(true);
  var Validate = ui.createSubmitButton("Validate").setEnabled(n>0).setVisible(true);
  var Buttons = ui.createHorizontalPanel().add(Back).add(Validate).add(Next);
  var Body = ui.createVerticalPanel().add(H1).add(H2).add(state).add(Buttons).add(getParameters(eventInfo));
  var Form = ui.createFormPanel().setId((n>0?'doPost[':'doGet[')+n+']').add(Body);

  // Add client handlers using setText() to adjust state prior to form submission
  // NB: Use of the .setValue(val) and .setValue(val,bool) methods give runtime errors!
  var onClickValidateHandler = ui.createClientHandler().forTargets(state).setText(''+(parseInt(n)));
  var onClickBackHandler = ui.createClientHandler().forTargets(state).setText(''+(parseInt(n)-1));
  Validate.addClickHandler(onClickValidateHandler);
  Back.addClickHandler(onClickBackHandler);

  // Add a client handler executed prior to form submission
  var onFormSubmit = ui.createClientHandler()
  .forTargets(state).setEnabled(true) // Enable so value gets included in post parameters
  .forTargets(Body).setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor","#EEE");    
  Form.addSubmitHandler(onFormSubmit);

  return Form;
}

function getParameters(eventInfo) {
  var ui = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var panel = ui.createVerticalPanel().add(ui.createLabel("Parameters: "));
  for( p in eventInfo.parameter)
    panel.add(ui.createLabel(" - " + p + " = " + eventInfo.parameter[p]));
  return panel;
}
```

The code uses a single "hidden" state (here visualized in a `TextBox`) and multiple `SubmitButton`'s to allow the user to advance forward and backward through the form sequence, as well as to validate the contents of the form.  The two extra `SubmitButton`'s are "rewired" using `ClientHandler`'s that simply modify the hidden state prior to form submission.

**Notes**

- Note the use of the `.setText(value)` method in the client handler's.  Using the Chrome browser I get weird runtime errors if I switch to either of the `TextBox`'s `.setValue(value)` or `.setValue(value, fireEvents)` methods.
- I tried (unsuccessfully) to implement this logic using a `Script Property` instead of the hidden TextBox.  Instead of client handlers, this requires using server handlers. The behavior is erratic, suggesting to me that the asynchronous server-side events are occurring after the form submission event.