# Google Apps Script Move Event From One Calendar To Another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I looked at *Mogsdad's* answer to a sort-of-similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557536/1986871), but it's not incredibly specific to my problem. I've also looked at the [documentation for the Calendar class and its subclasses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/), but there is no method (which should be implemented in my opinion; there is a pending [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1895&q=calendar&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)) for copying a **single** event from Calendar X to Calendar Y.

What I want to do is as follows:

1. Have the ID for the calendar event to be moved stored somewhere.
2. When Event Z is completed (external criteria, *not* time-based), give the function the calendar event ID.
3. The function will move Event Z from Calendar X to Calendar Y.

The only way I could think of how to do it is sloppy (semi-pseudo below):

```
// y is Calendar Y, z is the ID of Event Z
function moveToNewCalendar(y, z) {

var eventToMove = getEventByID(z);

// eventDetails is an Object
var eventDetails = getAllEventDetails(eventToMove); // This is not fun!

y.createEvent(eventDetails);
eventToMove.deleteEvent();
}

function getAllEventDetails(e) {

var details = {};

details["title"] = e.getTitle();
details["startTime"] = e.getStartTime();
// ... etc

return details;

}

function createEvent(eventDetails) {
// Create event using the information pulled from eventDetails
}
```

This functionality is available through the [Google Calendar API v3 - move](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move) function, but not through GAS.

I suppose that the main problem is copying the details of the event. There is no function to `createEvent(Event e)` in the Calendar prototype. Is there an easier way to do this that I'm just missing?

Comment: Good question ... if ever you write the code to get / set all event properties (as I'm afraid it will be the only way to get it done :-/) be kind enough to share it here !!

Comment: Alright, if this is the best way to do it until the developers implement their own function, then I'll get working on it! I'll update this question with the code as an answer when it is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [new library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/calendar) written by Romain Vialard will give you a complete solution... I had the pleasure to be a beta tester and all my tests were successful :-)

Comment: I wish I could upvote more! Thank you Romain Vialard, for giving us functionality that we all desire. I was going to finish up some other side-project before returning to writing the `moveToAnotherCalendar` function myself, I'm glad I came here beforehand to save myself from re-inventing the wheel. Now this should be implemented into the standard. If I'm not mistaken, Romain is a GAS project member is he not? In any case, I hope that people who need this library's functionality stumble across this SO question! Thanks again Serge, you're a GAS pro and I appreciate all your help :)

Comment: Thanks , Romain is a [top contributor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support) who has developed quite a lot of gas apps and libraries, have a look at the site he has with another brilliant TC, it's full of great stuff... :-)

Comment: Looks like this link is now broken. Is there a alternate link?

Comment: the advanced calendar app does that easily https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#reference  to move an event use var movedEvent = Calendar.Events.move(cal.id,ID,targetCal)