# Google script to move a calendar event from one calendar to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066197/google-apps-script-move-event-from-one-calendar-to-another) has a selected answer that no longer applies.  (Links to a dead library.)

Is there a way to use Google script to move an event from one calendar to another?  Inside the [developers guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar) for calendar, I see no such function.  Same again for the [Advanced Services guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar).

**Is there a function to move one calendar event from one calendar to another?**

**Update**

Details are key.  the two calendar ID's must contain '@group.calendar.google.com' at the end.  The event ID must NOT contain @google.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Move event from one calendar to another.**

```
Calendar.Events.move(sourceCalendarId, eventId, destinationCalendarId);
```

[Calendar API v3](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move)